# how to set two different NSUserDefaults in one UITextField

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsuserdefaults

i have new user registration and login page. When user creates new account i created `NSUserDefaults` method to save username and password after registration process completed i redirected to my login page with the help of `NSUserDefaults` method i place my username and password string in respective Textfield all this working fine for me.. But my actual doubt is when an existing user has an account he will enter is username and password and login and what i need is i need to capture the new user password and name so that when he reopen its login page i need to display its username and password in textfield

sample code :

**login page:**

```
 NSUserDefaults *prefs = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
 self.username.text = [prefs stringForKey:@"username1"];
 self.password.text = [prefs stringForKey:@"password1"];
```

**New user Page:**

```
NSUserDefaults *prefs = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
[prefs setObject:username.text forKey:@"username1"];
[prefs setObject:password.text forKey:@"password1"];
[prefs synchronize];
```

Comment: not an answer for you but you shouldn't store password in user defaults. you should use keychain for that kind of stuff.

Comment: Bad way of storing data!

Comment: can u plz tell me how to improve this code

Comment: @Anand Instead strong string in `NSUserDefaults` use `NSDictionary` with username as `key`

Comment: @Anand you shouldn't do so. Rather than displaying back the data stored in `NSUserDefaults`, you should store the credentials in Keychain (as Mert suggested), and perform auto-login for better User Experience.

Answer (score 0):

```
NSUserDefaults *userDefault = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
[userDefault setObject:@"user123" forKey:@"lastLoggedinUserName"];
[userDefault setObject:@"user123" forKey:@"lastLoggedinUserPassword"];
```

You can save user name and password of last logged-in user as above and whenever you are loading the login page in future load the lastLoggedinUser details in text field. You need to save the user credential each time when user perform the login into your application.

Comment: Its need to be done in login page. Once user login is successful, save these details.

Comment: ok fine when user creates new account in Registration page how can i save the string and display in login page ?

Comment: you just need to create a dictionary and save it in userdefault with username as key. Once user is created you can save last loggedinuser details and load it on login page

Comment: Plain text to store password ? No. Just NO.